# out of bounds!?! I don't see it

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, recursion, methods

Says I keep going out of bounds lines ([32],[36])I have changed almost everything I can think off. Any suggestions?

```
public class FindMaxRecursive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[5];
        System.out.println("Enter 5 integers: ");
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            a[i] = kbd.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("largest element in array: " + findMax(a, i));
    }

    public static int findMax(int[] a, int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            // exception on the next line
            return Math.max(a[i], findMax(a, i + 1)); 
        }

        else {
            return a[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Input, output & exception:

```
Enter 5 integers: 
1 2 3 4 5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Snippet.findMax(Snippet.java:19)
    at Snippet.main(Snippet.java:14)
```

At `findMax` within the `if` statement.

Comment: What does the stacktrace tell you?

Comment: Please include the full stack trace in your question, along with some indication of what line numbers are what, plus the input that triggers the error and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: Your `findMax` method is really completely broken. It seems that you don't really understand recursion; I suggest starting by changing your method to be non-recursive, so that you can get everything else working, and then focus on refactoring `findMax` into a recursive form (if desired).

Comment: OK, class name differs in exception, but I guess I'll leave it at this...

Comment: You bug is after the loop, i will be 5 and you try to print it with findMax. Or actually the bug is inside findMax, it should have another loop (and you dont need to give the length: `findMan(int[] is) { for(int n=0;n<is.lengt;n++) { ... } }`

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the `for` loop the variable `i` is left with `5`, so it points outside the array. (Valid indexes for the array are 0 through 4.)  So, when you use it later (inside `findMax()`) to address `a[i]`, you are accessing a non-existent element.

I would strongly advice you to learn to use a debugger so that you can find simple mistakes like this by yourself instead of having to ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: On a side note: it's great to know how to use a debugger, but sometimes, especially when writing smaller programs, it's overkill. Printing the variables involved, and maybe a few checkpoints to understand the flow of the program, is often all you need. I also consider it to be a great way to learn.

Comment: ***No***, using a debugger is absolutely ***never*** overkill, and ***no***, printing variables is not a great way to learn, using the debugger is a great way to learn. You must just get used to always hitting the `build + debug` key instead of the `build + run` key.  And, by the way, in all IDEs that I know of, `build + debug` is a simpler key combination than `build + run`.  There is a reason why it is so.

Comment: I totally agree with @MikeNakis. The debugger is your friend, using it should not be an obstacle.

Comment: @MikeNakis Suddenly we're talking about IDE's :p I assume you're still talking about not-so-small programs. My point is that forcing yourself to read and step through your code manually is a great way to learn while writing school assignments (which is definitely what we've got here).

Answer (score 0):

In the initial call to `findMax`, you are passing `i`, which has already been incremented to `5`.  But indexes in Java run from `0` through `length - 1`, or `4` here.  Pass `i - 1` to refer to the last position in your array.

However, you still attempt to look at positions `i` and `i + 1` in `findMax`, which will still be out of bounds.  The recursive method you have finds the maximum between the current element and the max of the rest of the array before it, so you will want to pass `i - 1`, not `i + 1`, in your recursive call.